# how can I get the value of x86-64 segment register fs?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I try to use `getcontext()` and use `REG_CSGSFS` to index into its `uc_mcontext`. However, I got a zero value. Is it correct?

Comment: getcontext and uc_mcontext are in the Linux kernel, and not c and c++. Please tag your question better!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways `fs` can work on x86_64: Either as a segment register indexing a descriptor in the LDT (nonzero value), or with a zero descriptor index and (hidden, maintained by the kernel) base offset to use when a `fs` segment prefix is seen.

Which mode is used depends on the location (high or low address) of the thread descriptor for the current thread.